# How to sum up all value returned by an array of threads in perl?

Tags: perl

I have threads that execute a sub which return an integer.

```
sub process_tasks {
    ...
    return($nb_item_processed);
}
```

Here is how I launch the threads

```
map { threads->new(\&process_tasks, $_) } 1 .. $nb_threads;
```

How can I compute the sum of all value returned ?

Comment: Use [Thread::Queue](http://p3rl.org/Thread::Queue). Use a result queue which you just dequeue and sum the values in the main thread.

Answer (score 5):

The value returned by a thread is returned by `join`.

```perl
use List::Util qw( sum );

my $sum =
   sum
      map { $_->join() }
         map { async { process_tasks($_) } }
            1 .. $nb_threads;
```